# Preciso de ajuda para criar uma condição para calcular a quantidade do produto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

O codigo abaixo está com a função de adicionar o item por checkbox, preciso de ajuda para que o mesmo fosse por quantidade, no caso input na qual o usuario irá inserir a quantidade e o mesmo calcular conforme a quantidade informada.

CODIGO JS

```
var pedido = "" 
const pedidosDisponiveis = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
var pedidoSelecionado = ""
var soma = 0; 
for ( pedido of pedidosDisponiveis) {
    var pedidoSelecionados = pedido.checked
    
    if(pedido.checked == true) {
        pedidoSelecionado +=` ${pedido.id} -> ${pedido.value} Reais; ` 
        var pedidosValores  =  parseInt(pedido.value)
        soma += pedidosValores   
    }
}
```

CODIGO HTML

```
<div class="item-txt">
    <strong>Pizza</strong>
    <span class="item-sub-txt"> Molho, mussarela, calabresa, cebola fatiada e orégano</span>
</div>

<div class="item-numeros-container">
    <div class="item_valor">
        <div>R$ 7,00</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item_quant">

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value=7,00 name="item-checkbox" class="item-checkbox"
                id="Pizza">
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Você pode substituir esse input do tipo checkbox por um input do tipo number, onde
nele você poderia definir o valor máximo e mínimo e ele só permitiria a entrada de
números.

Código HTML

```
      <div>
        <label for="quantidade">Quantidade:</label>
          <input type="number" id=quantidade min="1" max="10">
      </div>
```